# "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> " Error in Production but in development it work Properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error
"You should not use **`<Link>`** outside a **`<Router>`** " Error in Production after deployed on heroku ..... but in development (localhost) it work fine.

My **index.js** file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./components/Layout/layout.css";

import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";

import "assets/scss/material-kit-react.css?v=1.3.0";

let hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return(
          <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />
          );
      })}
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My **routes/index.jsx** file

```
import ContactUsPage from "views/ContactUsPage/ContactUsPage.jsx";
import AboutUsPage from "views/AboutUsPage/AboutUsPage.jsx";
import ServicePage from "views/ServicePage/ServicePage.jsx";
import ProjectsPage from "views/ProjectsPage/ProjectsPage.jsx";
import ComingSoonPage from "views/ComingSoonPage/ComingSoonPage.jsx"

import Home from "views/Home/Home.jsx";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

var indexRoutes = [
  { path: "/about-us", name: "AboutUsPage", component: AboutUsPage},
  { path: "/contact-us", name: "ContactUsPage", component: ContactUsPage},
  { path: "/services", name: "ServicePage", component: ServicePage},
  { path: "/projects", name: "ProjectsPage", component: ProjectsPage},
  { path: "/comingsoon", name: "ComingSoonPage", component: ComingSoonPage},
  { path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home}

];

export default indexRoutes;
```

Comment: Where are your `Link` components? Also, `component: {AboutUsPage}` looks a bit odd. Shouldn't it just be `component: AboutUsPage`?

Comment: There is no link component and basically i am using `a` tag href for linking.

Comment: Interesting. So you are doing a hard refresh every time you navigate instead? Are you using any `NavLink`s?

Comment: Yes i am using NavLinks

Comment: Are `<NavLinks />` used outside any components of the `<Router>`? That's the only reason this would happen.

Comment: No, there is no NavLink Outside the any Component router. Code is Running in LocalHost but when after deployed on Heroku...when opening URL link that time this error is sowing.